# WCF: Add Service reference creates message contract

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Proxy generated for WCF service creates Message contracts if I have the datatable/dataset data member though "Always generate message contracts" option unchecked. How can I force Data contract instead of Message Contract.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes.. I have been migrating vs2010 project into vs2013.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because that data types uses some .net dependencies. Its not fully interoperable. I suggest to not use any dataset or datatable. For example, declare your datatable structure into a class and return IEnumerable type.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yup. Done the same way :(, but I cant understand how come its working in Vs2010 and not in VS2013. Also since We need to change in lot of places and that is the main reason we were looking for some solutions, but couldn't get any.

Comment: understand very well. may you upgrade your service layer from remoting or etc. to wcf. There is no way without pain. You can look class generators. The generator most like to read database and creates poco classes from your tables. As i said, fully understand your case. I created new project for same case about 2 years ago. You can download at http://wcfcustomdataset.codeplex.com/ . but that is not a solution and not enough for your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I really dont understand what you are trying to say here :(